# Changing Administrator password Windows Home Server

Tags: windows-home-server

Is there a problem using Computer Management > Local User and Groups > Users to change the Administrator password in Windows Home Server?  Is there a chance it will cause any issues with the system?  I ask as the system warns against using server tools to change settings.  I have access to the system with my account, but the Administrator password isn't working,forgotten whatever and needs to be changed.

Answer (score 2):

The Administrator user's password can be freely changed if you've forgotten it, though Home Server recommends never using the built-in Administrator and only using a separate account that also has admin privs. Only changing system accounts would cause certain services to stop functioning (like the ASPNET account); the majority of the services, including backup, filesharing, and streaming, use one of the System accounts that have no passwords.

Comment: 'Windows Home Server console' only uses the Administrator to login (from what I can tell), or is there a way to use a different account?

Comment: You should be able to run the console under any user account that is a member of the Administrators group on the server. (Those are also the only accounts that can directly RDP in, unless you've hacked the terminal services dll.)

Answer (score 0):

[Easiest way to do it via the dashboard alone](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/reset-server-password-2.aspx)

With that said, the above method is doing the same thing as changing it via console would (in fact, technically, the dashboard is run over RDP....). The only additional functionality I see via dashboard is the ability to set a password hint.